# Why while changing the content in the text box is not changing the size of the scroll bars?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, scrollable

English is not my native language excuse me if there is grammar mistakes.
This is a program for a text editor.

### The Rule class is used as row header for ScrollableTextArea The ScrollableTextArea extends JTextArea and implements Scrollable it also  implementsMouseMotionListener so user can scroll(move the knob) by clicking on the track.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.Scrollable;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    /**
     *Classes required
     *Rule.java
     *ScrollableTextArea
     * @author Dev Parzival
     */
    public class Note extends JPanel{

        static int NUMBER_PANEL_WIDTH=50;
        private ScrollableTextArea scrollableTextArea;
        private Rule rowView;
        private JScrollPane scroll;

        public Note(Dimension size,File file) {

            rowView=new Rule(SwingConstants.VERTICAL,getIncrement());

            scrollableTextArea=new ScrollableTextArea(rowView.getIncrement());

            boolean flag=fetchData(scrollableTextArea, file);
            rowView.setPreferredHeight(scrollableTextArea.getHeight());
            if(!flag)
                return;
            scroll=new JScrollPane(scrollableTextArea);
            scroll.setPreferredSize(size);
            scroll.setRowHeaderView(rowView);
            scroll.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            add(scroll);
            setSize(size);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        private boolean fetchData(JTextArea text,File file){
            FileReader scan;
            BufferedReader br;
            try{
                scan=new FileReader(file);
                String msg="";
                br=new BufferedReader(scan);
                try{

                    while(true){
                        String data=br.readLine();
                        if(data==null)
                            break;
                        msg+=data+"\n";
                    }

                    text.setText(msg);
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error Occured while reading "+file.getAbsolutePath()+".","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Cannot found this path : "+file.getAbsoluteFile(),"Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        /*Here the unit is the height of the text inside the textArea*/
        public int getIncrement(){
            JTextArea ta=new JTextArea();
            return ta.getFontMetrics(ta.getFont()).getHeight();
        }
        public static void createAndShowGUI(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollDemo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            //Create and set up the content pane.
            JComponent newContentPane = new Note(frame.getSize(),new File("C:\\Users\\DevParzival\\Documents\\pro.txt"));
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

            //Display the window.
            //frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String $[]){
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class Rule extends JComponent {
        public static int INCH;
        public static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
        public static final int VERTICAL = 1;
        public static final int SIZE = 35;

        public int orientation;
        private int increment;
        private int units;

        public Rule(int o,int height) {
            orientation = o;
            INCH=height;
            setIncrementAndUnits();
        }


        private void setIncrementAndUnits() {
            increment = units=INCH;
        }

        public int getIncrement() {
            return increment;
        }

        public void setPreferredHeight(int ph) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, ph));
        }

        public void setPreferredWidth(int pw) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pw, SIZE));
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Rectangle drawHere = g.getClipBounds();

            System.out.println(drawHere);

            // Fill clipping area with dirty brown/orange.
            g.setColor(new Color(230, 163, 4));
            g.fillRect(drawHere.x, drawHere.y, drawHere.width, drawHere.height);

            // Do the ruler labels in a small font that's black.
            g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
            g.setColor(Color.black);

            // Some vars we need.
            int end = 0;
            int start = 0;
            int tickLength = 0;
            String text = null;

            // Use clipping bounds to calculate first and last tick locations.
            if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                start = (drawHere.x / increment) * increment;
                end = (((drawHere.x + drawHere.width) / increment) + 1)
                      * increment;
            } else {
                start = (drawHere.y / increment) * increment;
                end = (((drawHere.y + drawHere.height) / increment) + 1)
                      * increment;
            }

            // Make a special case of 0 to display the number
            // within the rule and draw a units label.
    //        if (start == 0) {
    //            text = Integer.toString(0);
    //            tickLength = 10;
    //            if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
    //                g.drawLine(0, SIZE-1, 0, SIZE-tickLength-1);
    //                g.drawString(text, 2, 21);
    //            } else {
    //                g.drawLine(SIZE-1, 0, SIZE-tickLength-1, 0);
    //                g.drawString(text, 9, 10);
    //            }
    //            text = null;
    //            start = increment;
    //        }

            // ticks and labels
            for (int i = start; i < end; i += increment) {
                if (i % units == 0)  {
                    tickLength = 10;
                    text = Integer.toString(i/units);
                } else {
                    tickLength = 7;
                    text = null;
                }

                if (tickLength != 0) {
                    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                        g.drawLine(i, SIZE-1, i, SIZE-tickLength-1);
                        if (text != null)
                            g.drawString(text, i-3, 21);
                    } else {
                        g.drawLine(SIZE-1, i, SIZE-tickLength-1, i);
                        if (text != null)
                            g.drawString(text, 9, i+3+increment/2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ScrollableTextArea extends JTextArea implements Scrollable,MouseMotionListener {
        private int maxUnitIncrement = 1;

        public ScrollableTextArea(int m) {

            maxUnitIncrement = m;

            //Let the user scroll by dragging to outside the window.
            setAutoscrolls(true); //enable synthetic drag events
            addMouseMotionListener(this); //handle mouse drags
        }

        //Methods required by the MouseMotionListener interface:
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            //The user is dragging us, so scroll!
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
            scrollRectToVisible(r);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500,500);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                              int orientation,
                                              int direction) {
            //Get the current position.
            int currentPosition = 0;
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                currentPosition = visibleRect.x;
            } else {
                currentPosition = visibleRect.y;
            }

            //Return the number of pixels between currentPosition
            //and the nearest tick mark in the indicated direction.
            if (direction < 0) {
                int newPosition = currentPosition -
                                 (currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement)
                                  * maxUnitIncrement;
                return (newPosition == 0) ? maxUnitIncrement : newPosition;
            } else {
                return ((currentPosition / maxUnitIncrement) + 1)
                       * maxUnitIncrement
                       - currentPosition;
            }
        }

        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                               int orientation,
                                               int direction) {
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                return visibleRect.width - maxUnitIncrement;
            } else {
                return visibleRect.height - maxUnitIncrement;
            }
        }

        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

        public void setMaxUnitIncrement(int pixels) {
            maxUnitIncrement = pixels;
        }
    }
```

[image: Above Pic]

> From the above pic it is visible that changing the content of the
>      textArea is not changing the size of the scroll bars.
>      How could we make the scroll bar to adjust as the content inside the scrollableTextArea changes?
>      How to fix the bug?
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scroll.setPreferredSize(size);` is a bad idea. `JTextArea and implements Scrollable` - `JTextArea` already implements `Scrollable` - not an issue, but it's just messy

Comment: Don't override `getPreferredSize` of the `JTextArea`, otherwise it can never grow - as it can not longer calculate the size it needs.  Use `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` to define the "desired" size the component should have when contained within the `JScrollPane`

Comment: Thanks bro for help